# How do I make an audio file play with JavaScript when a web page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, playback

I want an audio file to play automatically when a web page loads. I've tried the following simple code but for some reason it's not working. Any thoughts? I understand this may be caused by some default behavior of Google Chrome. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Audio</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
  const audio = new Audio("wonderful.mp3");
  audio.play();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Browsers prevent pages from auto-playing audio (and for good reason) Check the console and you will see an error along the lines of "can't play audio without user interaction"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't.
Browsers don't allow you to play audio when the user has not interacted with your site at least once.
You should create a simple function that, when the user click for the first time on your page, play your audio.

`Error : Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

This snippet allows you to play your audio when the user click on your document for the first time :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Audio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>Test</div>


    <audio id="my-audio" autoplay
        src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fe8bd9dfd063066d39cfd5a/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3"></audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var isAudioPlayed = false;



        function playAudio() {
            
            isAudioPlayed = true;
            const myAudio = document.getElementById("my-audio");
            myAudio.play();
        }


        document.body.onclick = ()=>{
            if(isAudioPlayed) return ;
            playAudio();
        }

/*         
        window.onload = () => {
            const myAudio = document.getElementById("my-audio");
            console.log(myAudio);
            myAudio.addEventListener('canplay', (event) => {  
                console.log("CnPlay",event)
                    event.target.play()
            })
        }
 */

        

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Else you can use [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) event

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm obviously going up the wrong tree. :-) My goal is to find an automated way to play an audio file (at a specific time) that lives on another server such as Mixcloud.com, just by passing it a URL.

Comment: so you want to play audio for example at the second minute or something like that ?